# Running textcleaner against ImageMagick compressed images

Tags: compression, imagemagick, ocr, tesseract

I am trying to use the [textcleaner](http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/textcleaner/) script for cleaning up real life images that I am using with OCR. The issue I am having is that the images sent to me are rather large sometimes. (3.5mb - 5mb 12MP pics) The command I run with textcleaner ( `textcleaner -g -e none -f <int @ 10 - 100> -o 5 result1.jpg out1.jpg` ) takes about 10 seconds at `-f 10` and minutes or more on a `-f 100`.

To get around this I tried using ImageMagick to compress the image so it was much smaller. Using  `convert -strip -interlace Plane -gaussian-blur 0.05 -quality 50% main.jpg result1.jpg` I was able to take a 3.5mb and convert it almost loss-lessly to ~400kb. However when I run textcleaner on this new file it STILL acts like its a 3.5mb file. (Times are almost exactly the same). I have tested these textcleaner settings against a file NOT compressed @400kb and it is almost instant while -f 100 takes about 12 seconds.

I am about out of ideas. I would like to follow  the example [here](http://vbridge.co.uk/2012/11/05/how-we-tuned-tesseract-to-perform-as-well-as-a-commercial-ocr-package/#comment-10211) as I am in almost exactly the same situation. However, at the current speed of transformation an entire OCR process could take over 10 minutes when I need this to be around 30 seconds.

Comment: Can you provide a (link to a) sample 3.5MB file, as well as one to a *"NOT compressed @400kb"* one?

Comment: The `-f 100` setting of textcleaner -- why do you need to use it at all? The value for `-f` (*filtersize*) in `textcleaner` is required to be only slightly higher than the thickness of the writing -- increasing beyond that is paid for (as you noticed) with slowness and additionally with lost characters (as you may not yet have noticed)!

Comment: First off I have figured out what is going on. According to Fred himself, the textcleaner script uncompresses the image before doing its work. This means that my compression is pointless in this case. 

Also I am using values of -f as high as 100 via this website http://vbridge.co.uk/2012/11/05/how-we-tuned-tesseract-to-perform-as-well-as-a-commercial-ocr-package/#comment-10211. Although I am finding that anything over 50 tends to be too much

Comment: *"the textcleaner script uncompresses the image before doing its work. This means that my compression is pointless in this case."*: That's what I was going to hint at too after having had a look at the script's code. The script does its work pixel by pixel. So even if there are less kBytes in the file, as long as there is the same number of pixels, it will be the same speed. Since you don't provide a (link to a) sample file, there is nothing much to add in advice for you, other than: (see next comment) ...

Comment: ... most OCR software works well with 200 to 300 dpi. So maybe *scaling down* your 12 MegaPixel files could keep the OCR-ability while speeding it up?

Comment: I have actually begun to use the command ` mogrify -quality "<quality>%" -resize 2048x2048 -filter Lanczos -interlace Plane -gaussian-blur 0.05 test.jpg` and it actually reduces the image size without compression. However I can't find its equivalent in PHP's imagemagick library. Any ideas?

Comment: Don't use `mogrify`. `convert` should work just as well. *(This is the last response, unless you provide a sample image to look at.)*

Comment: I have to use `mogrify` as it makes the image smaller and textcleaner now has 1/10th the run time. When using `convert` that doesn't happen. So `mogrify` it is

Comment: No, you don't have to use `mogrify`. I meant this: Use `convert` ***with the same arguments*** as you used for `mogrify`. Also, I wouldn't output JPEG. Better to use a lossless format. What format does your OCR take as input?